# ACS review condition failure

Tags: json, titanium

I'm working in an android app using Titanium appcelerator.
Now i'm trying out ***ACS REVIEWS***  .. I'm getting the whole db result , i need to filter by id. For that i tried to put **Where** condition ..But it doesn't working..

*My Json*

```
  {
    "id": "52ea3eba08a3e5704b330c2a2a",
    "rating": 3,
    "created_at": "2014-01-30T11:59:54+0000",
    "updated_at": "2014-01-30T11:59:54+0000",
    "user": {
      "id": "52e5f3881356b440b4b09c805",
      "created_at": "2014-01-27T05:50:00+0000",
      "updated_at": "2014-01-29T04:29:49+0000",
      "external_accounts": [

      ],
      "confirmed_at": "2014-01-27T05:50:00+0000",
      "username": "Gk",
      "role": "j",
      "admin": "false",
      "custom_fields": {
        "phone": "91959454651",
        "usertype": "0",
        "status": "1",
        "ios_deviceid": "",
        "country_code": "IN",
        "verify_code": "4574",
        "verified": "1",
        "contact_sms": "1",
        "contact_message": "1",
        "contact_email": "1",
        "contact_phone": "0",
        "android_gcmid": "APA91bE0mcScNlXbCENZ2D_9jylgwdwOJ6vYTqnI_Kzqx2lqLWblnn6mT4PJ6iZRNxUGA66Ke7RJ0CKC44DL3mturNs_w3QT7KhTVIWbQE2tJgBHU7gpzB2GG4sFGXL6LiayJ5zEn_AGhxBlw"
      }
    },
    "reviewed_object": {
      "type": "Post",
      "id": "52e7800313556440b4b0aa134"
    },
    "custom_fields": {
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "52ea3e9d4430d0b1e0c1c16",
    "rating": 3,
    "created_at": "2014-01-30T11:59:25+0000",
    "updated_at": "2014-01-30T11:59:25+0000",
    "user": {
      "id": "52e8fe464643d0b130b85f5",
      "first_name": "Ganesh",
      "last_name": "test",
      "created_at": "2014-01-29T13:12:38+0000",
      "updated_at": "2014-01-29T13:12:38+0000",
      "external_accounts": [

      ],
      "confirmed_at": "2014-01-29T13:12:38+0000",
      "username": "john",
      "role": "r",
      "admin": "false"
    },
    "reviewed_object": {
      "type": "Post",
      "id": "52e7800343556b4dsfsdfh3434"
    },
    "custom_fields": {
    }
  },  
]
```

I want to filter using this id..

```
 "reviewed_object": {
      "type": "Post",
      "id": "52e7800343556b4dsfsdfh3434"
    }
```

What should i write in my WHERE Condition..

```
Cloud.Reviews.query({
            page : 1,
            per_page : 20,
            where : {
                rating : {
                    '$gt' : 1.0
                },

            },
            order : "-created_at"

        }
```

Comment: anybody attempted this one;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have added my post id condition without where statement ..It worked perfectly..

**My Code:**

```
Cloud.Reviews.query({
            page :1,
            per_page : 20,
            post_id : Your Post id

        }, function(e) {
            if (e.success) {
```